# does clearTimeout works with let and const?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can't seem to get it to work.

```
openContactUsForm(stop: Boolean = false) {
  let openContactForm = setTimeout(() => {
    $('#myButton').click();
  }, 6000);
  if (stop) {
    clearTimeout(openContactForm);
    $('#myButton').click();
  }
}
```

The timeout still clicks after 6 seconds even after passing the `stop` boolean as `true`

Comment: How exactly are you calling this method? Do you call it first with no stop param (aka false) and then calling the same method with true? If so you cannot expect to make the timeout from the first call to be stopped by the second call.

Comment: This seems to work. Where is this being used?

Here's a working demo: http://jsbin.com/laqideqari/2/edit?js,console,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From how it sounds you are calling the method once, then calling it again with stop passed in as true. In that case both times you call the method, the `openContactForm` is defined all over again. One way you can do this if you are in a react component is setting the timer as a property on the component.

If you are doing ES6 classes you can define it initially in the constructor

```
constructor() {
  super()
  this.timer = null;
}

openContactUsForm(stop: Boolean = false) {
 if (stop) {
    clearTimeout(this.timer);
    $('#myButton').click();
    return;
  }
  this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
    $('#myButton').click();
  }, 6000);

}
```

if your tags are wrong and not using reactjs, you just need to define the timer in the top level scope that way it isn't being rewritten everytime you call that function, causing the timer id to change and not stopping the original timer.

Comment: This is not really different to the code the OP wrote. If called with `stop` as `true` then then previously stored timeout id is overwritten, and the newly stored one is immediately cleared.